# Unable to access Hidden Field value in server side

Tags: asp.net, field, hidden

I have a hidden field for which I assign value in javascript like so.

```
    var rowIndex;
    function GetSelectedRow(lnk) {
        var row = lnk.parentNode.parentNode;
        rowIndex = row.rowIndex - 1;
        var RI = rowIndex;
        document.getElementById('<%= HiddenRowIndex.ClientID%>').value = RI;
        }
```

In server side I try to get the field like

```
    Dim dtsub As New DataTable
    dtsub = CType(ViewState("UploadTimeSlotGroupData"), DataTable)
    Dim dtRow() As DataRow = dtsub.Select(expression)

    If dtRow(0) IsNot Nothing Then
        dtsub.Rows(Val(HiddenRowIndex.Value.ToString)).Delete()
    End If
```

But I am getting only 0 in server side. How do I fix this?

Comment: Maybe your variable `RI` is really `0`.

Comment: No, I tried getting the value in alert. It displays the row index.

Comment: after `var RI = rowIndex;` do `alert(RI);`,to it's value first and do `alert` for `document.getElementById('<%= HiddenRowIndex.ClientID%>').value` as well..

Comment: are you using `runat="server"` into your `hiddenfield`.

Comment: @Rahul,I get the values perfectly in client side. But it is always 0 in server.

Comment: If you get alert correctly, it's not client-side error. You must debug your server side code.

Comment: I just wanna know whether there's any error in my codes.

Comment: @Aishvarya I don't know about `asp.net` and `vb`. I check the client-side code in my computer and it works correctly, so what happend to its value, is in server side. Maybe you should debug `HiddenRowIndex.Value` alone and complete it step by step...

Comment: maybe you are (re)setting the value before processing the deleteEventHandler in the page life-cycle(missing a _if(!IsPostBack)_ somewhere for example )

Comment: I set the value to -1 in the click event of a button. Is that the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have fixed the issue. The code:

```
        function GetSelectedRow(lnk) {
        var row = lnk.parentNode.parentNode;
        rowIndex = row.rowIndex - 1;
        var RI = rowIndex;
        document.getElementById('<%= HiddenRowIndex.ClientID%>').value = RI;
        }
```

Comment: your new code is just like old one,,where is the problem and what you correct.

Answer (score 0):

Use `runat="server"` in hiddenfield tag if you have used `<input type="hidden">`